# why error angularjs Error: $compile:tpload Error Loading Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm studying angularjs and little find constraint error :

> $compile:tpload Error Loading Template

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="latihan7">
<head>
    <title>Learn</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div header-page></div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('latihan7',[]);

app.directive('headerPage',function(){
    return{ 
        templateUrl : 'header.html'
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**header.html**

```
<h2>test header</h2>
```

Comment: That means that our template couldn't be load open the network panel and check the URL for header.html

Comment: You'll get this error if the server returns 404 for the requested resource

Comment: Where is `header.html` located? If it's in the same folder try doing `templateUrl: './header.html'`

Comment: in same folder and still the error @Goliadkin

Comment: [This are the error docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload). What is the project structure, are you using some kind of bundler perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It means your template is not accessible. Note that you can provide your template in the same HTML like this to avoid dealing with relative path troubles:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="header.html">
    <h2>test template</h2>
</script>
```

Also, here's your [working example](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/gmoMaP?editors=1010#0)

Answer (score 0):

`Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template` tells you that the template is not accessible. Make sure the path to your `header.html` file is correct.

you can test the html path is correct by opening the template in the browser, like this.

http://localhsot:80/ur_app/header.html

working [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/HlPkKJvbwmipLsCvHKsD?p=preview)